# transfer abbreviation string to detail info sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-analytics

I have a table which have two strings user_id,and user_activities_type .
exp.

```
'John',   '23Lqv'
'Mike', '159pLv3'
```

Every word in the user_activities_type has it's own meaning like

```
2-> take math lessons
3 -> take english lessons
L -> take chemical lessons
```

The result I want is

```
'John' ,'math,english,chemical'
'Mike','history,english,painting'
```

Is there anyway to make it by sql ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is. The meaning of activities type... is that in a second table? (If not, how do you know what each code means?) Also, are all the activity meanings in the same format, 'take zzz lessons', and you want to just use the middle word? Or are "take" and "lessons" understood, and the table only shows "math", "English" etc.? Finally, does the order of the codes as in 23L have meaning? Do you want the words in the string to follow the same order as 2, 3, L?

Comment: Yes, the detail meanings are in another table, and the table stroe data like '3','english'   'L','chemical'

Comment: Also, you realize that's a very flawed data model, right? If you don't know what I mean, please read about "First Normal Form" (google)

Comment: Sorry...the table already there for long, and I have to get data that way now

Answer (score 1):

You have a really, really, really lousy data structure.  I would advocate that you change it with one row per user and per activity, along with an activities table.  This is a more typical normalized data model, and more appropriate for a relational database.

But, you could do:

```
select user_id,
       concat_ws(',',
                 (case when user_activities_type like '%1%' then 'history' end),
                 (case when user_activities_type like '%2%' then 'math' end),
                 (case when user_activities_type like '%3%' then 'english' end),
                 . . .
                )
from t;
```

EDIT:

Ooops.  I didn't realize that this was Oracle.

```
select user_id,
       substr(',' || (case when user_activities_type like '%1%' then 'history' end) ||
              ',' || (case when user_activities_type like '%2%' then 'math' end) ||
              ',' || (case when user_activities_type like '%3%' then 'english' end)
                 . . .
               2)
from t;
```

Comment: Not sure what that means - can you elaborate?

Comment: why did u use substr(... ,2); for

Comment: @sql_dummy . . . To skip the first character.

Comment: Seriously, how is this going to work? How will you deal with user_activities_type strings of variable length, or even of length that is not known ahead of time? Surely  ...  is not your answer.

Comment: @mathguy . . . It looks for the codes and puts in the expanded name for each matching code.  It does not keep the original order of the values, but it should put in the expanded names for every code in `user_activities_type`.

Comment: Got it. But - you are hard coding the activity types, when the OP said they are in a table. What are you going to do when new activity types are added? Also, presumably the strings encode class schedules, so order is important (and perhaps duplicates must be allowed).

Comment: @mathguy . . . Nothing in the question suggests to me that they are in a table.  Note the first paragraph is how the OP says that s/he has a table.  The second simply says that they codes have meanings.

Comment: Those meanings must come from some place. That was my first comment to the OP, and the answer "yes, they are in another table" was his reply.

Answer (score 0):

Tables:

```
users

    USER ACTIVITY_TYPE
    ---- ---------------
    John 23L
    Mike 159

activities

    ACTIVITY_CODE        DESCRIPTION
    -------------------- --------------------
    1                    music
    2                    math
    3                    english
    5                    physics
    9                    french
    L                    chemistry
```

Query:

```
select user_id, listagg(description, ',') within group (order by rk) as activities_list
from (select user_id, rk, description from users u join 
         (select rownum rk from all_tables) r on r.rk <= length(activity_type)
         join activities a on a.activity_code = substr(u.activity_type, rk, 1)  )
group by user_id
/
```

Result:

```
USER ACTIVITIES_LIST
---- --------------------------------------------------
John math,english,chemistry
Mike music,physics,french
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is the most amazing code I have ever seen. Amazing Oracle function. But what a shame I am using Netezza as my database.

Comment: ??  Then who tagged your question as "Oracle"? Sorry, I am not familiar with Netezza; if you tag your question correctly, perhaps you will get the help you need.